# What tool can I use to explore a scene created with blender?

Tags: external-applications

I want to use a generic tool/game/app (either on PC, or on Android, or as a web page) that loads a scene, and allows me to move around in that scene at eye level, and look around. It's not just for me, it's also for friends and family, so it has to be super easy to install and start.

15 years ago, I was exporting the scene as a Quake 3 map, then I would just "play" that map to explore it. That was perfect: easy to install, easy to load a custom map, nice feeling of walking around.

What would be the right tool today?

Comment: You can load the scene in blender and navigate though it using walk mode.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0mcAL3sWRM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put it on Sketchfab or just place it in Unity with the standard  player model